# bash error : Cannot find /Library/...../setclasspath.sh, but it's there

Tags: macos, bash, tomcat, terminal

I'm trying to set up tomcat server and I am using the instructions from a website that has instructed me to

```
      # Execute the Tomcat startup script
      ./startup.sh
```

but when i enter the ./startup.sh command i get an error

```
      Cannot find /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/setclasspath.sh
```

but the setclasspath.sh is there (see screenshot below):

[image]

What am i doing wrong????

---

now i cannot cd to Home  (see screenshot below):

[image]

here is the path info:
[image]

Comment: is that directory listing from /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin? Your cd command appears to be chopped off.

Comment: post the output for `pwd` on that directory.

Comment: belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Turns out it was bin in apache-tomcat-6.0.35... not in Home... but when i cd to Home i get another error i'll post it above

Comment: Could you do an `ls -al` where the `Home` directory is. And as @nims says, a `pwd` would be good.

Answer (score 64):

I had same problem on my mountain lion machine and I use this command :

```
$ unset CATALINA_HOME
```

and after that it solved my problem.This command will unset the environmental variable `CATALINA_HOME`.

Comment: I was suffering from error: Cannot find /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program. Your tip solved my problem! THANKS

Answer (score 14):

just run: 
$ unset CATALINA_HOME
in Terminal, and it works again.

Comment: Save my day. Thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

Please RESET the CATALINA_HOME to point to correct path. That should resolved the problem.
for example; currently it might be at "/usr/share/tomcat6/" but you need to verify & point till the correct directory like "/usr/share/tomcat6/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/"

Answer (score 4):

Its because of permission, you can run this using root
`$ sudo pathtotomcat/bin/./startup.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I too had similar issue and I am able to resolve it by simply changing the file permission of tomcat folder . Make it read and Write for everyone. And sh `startup.sh` command would work fine with Tomcat/7.0.34

[I got this solution from here](http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7)

To make all scripts runnable:

```
sudo chmod +x /Library/Tomcat/bin/*.sh
```

I hope it solves your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of ali is good, but for some reason I also needed to open .bash_profile and comment out CATALINA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

This happens almost definitely because of incorrect value of `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable in your current shell. In my case for example I had an older tomcat install that I removed and installed another version but forgot to change the env var set in `.bash_profile`. So any of the methods suggested which remove the var will work. If you have `CATALINA_HOME` set in `.bash_profile`, remove it.  `unset CATALINA_HOME` would work too but if its in profile, it will again be set when you open a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

Although all mentioned answers look fine it's a good idea to be aware the main reason.

Somewhere on your operating system, a file is setting environment variables for your operating system, one of those variable names is `CATALINA_HOME` which is pointing to an address or path. when you attempt to run `./startup.sh` or `catalina.sh run`, these command needs the `CATALINA_HOME` which is set by your operating system and will override the default `CATALINA_HOME` of tomcat configuration. (You may have used tomcat and set this variable before and now you forget it)

So the main solution is to edit that special file and it really depends on operating system. In my case, `Fedora`, two files are candidate one of them is `~/.bashrc` and another one is `/etc/profile`. After editing them you need to `source` them or `log out` and then `log in` (On `OS X` I think it should be in `/Users/username/.bash_profile` file).

of course `unset CATALINA_HOME` command works but after closing and opening a new terminal, again you need to use this command due to refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

U need to set two lines at two places

path details

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.90

put this path at the end of the lines

files that you want to edit 
 vi ~/.bashrc
 vi ~/.bash_profile

./shutdown.sh
./startup.sh

its works for me